# How to check if an input is in a set of values in java?

Tags: java, validation, input

I need to take a character as input and check to see if it is either a number (0 - 9) or +-*/
how can I do this in an elegant way without checking each one individually?

Comment: For the digit, you can use `Character.isDigit(char)`

Comment: You could use a regular expression to specify your matching criteria.

Comment: Put your alphabet in a string a check whether the string contains the input.

Answer (score 1):

If you are parsing a mathematical equation and want to verify that you have a valid mathematical equation the only way to do it *correctly* is to build a state machine and check each char individually.

If you just want to verify that only those 14 characters are in the string then you can use a regular expression or String.contains().

Comment: Is there a way to use String.contains() to find out if the string doesn't contain anything but those values?

Comment: @user3002830 From [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html), `replaceAll`  followed by `isEmpty` might be better suited for checking if it contains values other than those specified.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the character's ASCII decimal representation.

```
        int asInt = (int)c;

    if (asInt >= 48 && asInt <= 57)
        System.out.println("Digit range");
    else {
        switch (asInt) {
        case 42: System.out.println("Is multiplication sign.");break;
        case 43: System.out.println("Is plus sign.");break;
        case 45: System.out.println("Is less sign.");break;
        case 47: System.out.println("Is division sign.");break;
        default: System.out.println("This is something we weren't expecting.");
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't think this is a very clean way to do this, but I think it's worth pointing out that you don't need to use the ASCII values directly.  You can `switch` on both String and char.